# JS: update the data in a specific object by key

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here's my array:

```
const mockData = [
    {
      text: 'Text1',
      data: [
        { field: '1' },
        { field: '2' },
        { field: '3' },
        { field: '4' },
        { field: '5' },
        { field: '6' }
      ]
    },
    {
      text: 'Text2',
      data: [{ field: '1' }, { field: '2' }, { field: '3' }, { field: '4' }]
    }
  ];
```

I need to update the `data` in a specific object by `text` property. For example, if I define the key as `Text1` I need to update the `data` in first object of the array.

Basically, I need a method like `updateArray(key, data).`

I would like to use it like:

```
const dataToUpdate = [{field: '777'}]

updateArray('Text1', dataToUpdate);
```

Output:

```
const mockData = [
    {
      text: 'Text1',
      data: [{field: '777'}]
    },
    {
      text: 'Text2',
      data: [{ field: '1' }, { field: '2' }, { field: '3' }, { field: '4' }]
    }
  ];
```

Here's what I've tried so far to slice a specific object property, but the question is how to update it with a new data:

```
const sliceArray = (data, target, len = 3) => 
  data.map(({ text, data, ...rest}) => ({
    data: text == target ? data.slice(0, len) : data,
    text,
    ...rest
  }))

console.log(sliceArray(mockData, 'Text1'))
```

Comment: And the problem you're having is? You can use `.find()` to find the element with a specific `text` property, and then push the new data onto the `data` array.

Comment: @Barmar I'll be grateful if you can show me an example. Thanks!

Comment: @Barmar Thank you! Updated the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the new data rather than a count.

```
const replaceArray = (data, target, newData) => 
  data.map(({ text, data, ...rest}) => ({
    data: text == target ? newData : data,
    text,
    ...rest
  }))

console.log(replaceArray(mockData, 'Text1', dataToUpdate))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
function updateArray(key, dataToUpdate) {
    mockData.forEach(data => {
        if (data.text === key) {
          data.data = dataToUpdate;
        }
    })
}
```

Basically, loop through the mocked data array and then check if the text property of each object matches the key, if so, then update the its data.